# RestKit: POST deserialisation - Expected an object mapping for class of type A, provider returned one for B

Tags: ios, restkit

Heres my routing setup:

```
[manager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[UserProfile class]  pathPattern:@"/api/v1/users" method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];
[manager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[UserProfileAndStatistics class]  pathPattern:@"/api/v1/profile/:userId" method:RKRequestMethodGET]];
[manager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[PrivateUserProfile class] pathPattern:@"/api/v1/privateprofile/" method:RKRequestMethodGET]];
[manager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[PrivateUserProfile class] pathPattern:@"/api/v1/privateprofile/" method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];
```

And here is how I register the mappings:

```
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:nil];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    //the serialisation step
    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[mapping inverseMapping] objectClass:[mapping objectClass] rootKeyPath:nil];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
```

Finally I call:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:userProfile path:nil parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) { ... }
```

Which posts correctly, I get a HTTP status code 200, and the data goes to the server. This means that the serialisation step is working. When the response comes back I get an error:

```
Adding mapping error: Expected an object mapping for class of type 'PrivateUserProfile', provider returned one for 'UserProfileAndStatistics'
```

Now the mappings for `PrivateUserProfile` and `UserProfileAndStatistics` are very similar

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[PrivateUserProfile class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"UserIdentifier" :   @"userId",
 @"UserName"       :   @"userName",
 @"Name"           :   @"name",
 @"Email"          :   @"emailAddress",
 @"Bio"            :   @"bio",
 @"Website"        :   @"webSite",
 @"Avatar"         :   @"avatar"
 }];

RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[UserProfileAndStatistics class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"UserIdentifier" :   @"userId",
 @"UserName"       :   @"userName",
 @"Name"           :   @"name",
 @"Bio"            :   @"bio",
 @"Website"        :   @"webSite",
 @"Avatar"         :   @"avatar",
 @"Posts"          :   @"posts",
 @"Followers"      :   @"followers",
 @"Following"      :   @"following"
 }];
```

But why does RestKit choose one over the other? How do I debug this successfully? Is there a relationship between RKRoute and RKObjectMapping. The mapping for PrivateUserProfile is being used for the serialisation step, so why isn't it being used for the counterpart deserialisation, and how do I make it get used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two response descriptors here - one with path `/api/v1/privateprofile/` for class `PrivateUserProfile` and the other with path `/api/v1/profile/:userId` for class `UserProfileAndStatistics`:

```
[manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[

 [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:privateUserProfileMapping
                                         pathPattern:@"/api/v1/privateprofile/"
                                             keyPath:nil
                                         statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)],
 [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:userProfileAndStatisticsMapping
                                         pathPattern:@"/api/v1/profile/:userId"
                                             keyPath:nil
                                         statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]
 ]];
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. Am I to understand from your answer that there is no relationship between RKRoute and RKObjectMapping when it comes to responses? It seems a (DRY) pity to set up a routing that encapsulates the url and then have to specify it again in the response descriptor. Is there any way that you only have to do this once?

Comment: I don't know. That's a good question - perhaps you could ask on the Google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/restkit